# Spring Boot 2.5.0, Spring Cloud 2020.0.2 and Hibernate 5.4.31 - H2 Database Multi Row Insert Failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

While Working on a Spring Boot Application with SB version 2.5.0, Spring Cloud (for Centralized Config 2020.0.2)
The Hibernate version is 5.4.31 (I am not using a specific Hibernate version, it is as per Spring Boot compatibility).
Using H2 database for in-memory data, as I need to create the sample application for demo.

In the Resources folder, I do have my SQL file.
When I name it `data.sql` the application does not start at all.
When I renamed this file as `import.sql`, my application started but still facing issues for multi-row insertion.

*Data Insert SQL File*

```
/* Data for Entity DataTable */
    INSERT INTO data_table (name) VALUES
    ('Data 1'),
    ('Data 2'),
    ('Data 3');
```

This was working perfectly fine when my Application is running with Spring Boot 2.3.10.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR5.

I have also tried the properties of JPA and Hibernate to resolve this issue, but still no success. Find properties which I use are as below:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

Due to updating the Spring Boot and Spring Cloud version, I am not sure if there is anything I specifically need to set the H2 Database to work for Multi-Row insert.

Looks to be something relevant to Hibernate or H2 Database Issue.

```
WARN 7952 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHand lerLoggedImpl    : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "('Data 2')" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "('Data 2')" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.31.Final.jar!/:5.4.31.Final]

...
...
...

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "('Data 2'[*]),"; expected "(, WITH, SELECT, TABLE, VALUES"; SQL statement: ('Data 2'), [42001-200]
```

**UPDATE**

I have reverted my SQL file name to data.sql, and then I observed the same H2 database exception is coming and the application does not startup.

Find below details for startup execution which I am getting:

```
WARN 4720 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException:

Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [jar:file:/D:/Projects/SpringCloudDemoApp/spring-cloud-demo/target/demo-data-service-0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/data.sql]: INSERT INTO data_table (name) VALUES ('Data 1'), ('Data 2'), ('Data 3'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "DATA_TABLE" not found; SQL statement: INSERT INTO data_table (name) VALUES ('Data 1'), ('Data 2'), ('Data 3') [42102-200]

...
...

ERROR 4720 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQLscript statement #1 of URL [jar:file:/D:/Projects/SpringCloudDemoApp/spring-cloud-demo/target/demo-data-service-0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/data.sql]: INSERT INTO data_table (name) VALUES ('Data 1'), ('Data 2'), ('Data 3'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "DATA_TABLE" not found; SQL statement: INSERT INTO data_table (name) VALUES ('Data 1'), ('Data 2'), ('Data 3') [42102-200]
```

Also please find my Entity class in case something wrong with this, but don't think so anything wrong with Entity class as it works well with older Spring Boot and Spring Cloud versions, but still sharing here.

*DataTable Entity Class*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_table")
public class DataTable {   

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "dataid")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 200)
    private String name;

    // Getter Setters will follow here
}
```

*Application YML file*

```
server:
    port: 9090
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:demodb
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: scdemo
        password: scdemopass
    jpa:
        properties:
            hibernate:
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
                jdbc:
                    batch_size: 20
                order_inserts: true
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: true
            path: /h2-console
            settings:
                trace: false
```

***IMPORTANT UPDATE***

I also tried the same, only with Spring Boot 2.5.0 and JPA, Hibernate with H2 Database, created a sample application which has only 4 files, The Spring Boot Application file to start and the Entity class, `data.sql` as above, and the `application.yml` for configurations and made sure that it fails for the same condition. And I confirm that I am getting the same error to load data from the `data.sql` to insert, which works well with the older Spring Boot Release.

I just updated the SB version from `2.5.0` to `2.3.10.RELEASE`, and the same code worked.

***More Details***:

1. When the `data.sql` file is used with Spring Boot Version `2.3.10.RELEASE` and the Insert Statements in the `data.sql` file are multi-row and are on multiple lines. It works perfectly fine.
2. When `data.sql` renamed as an `import.sql`, with Spring Boot version 2.5.0 and the Insert Statements in the `import.sql` file are multi-row but it is expected to keep all values on the same line, this also works well.
3. When `data.sql` renamed as an `import.sql`, with Spring Boot version `2.5.0` and the Insert Statements in the `import.sql` file are multi-row and are on multiple lines, this scenario fails. As it considers the statement on each new line as DDL. In this case Application Runs but the data insert does not take place.

   ```
   GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "('Data 3')" via JDBC Statement
   ```
4. And the 4th Case is when `data.sql` with Spring Boot version `2.5.0` and the Insert Statements in the `data.sql` file are multi-row and are on multiple lines,  this scenario fails too At the time of Data Source Initialization and Application do not run at all.

Sharing the Sample Code for the same:
The source code can be tried with the 4 conditions mentioned above:
[demo-data-service](https://github.com/get2mandar/demo-data-service)

Please suggest.

Comment: What are the issues? How does the insert fail?

Comment: Added the Error Details, which might give some clue, that what is the issue.  I realized that issue looks to be with Hibernate version or H2 DB. But not sure, Multi-Row insert was working correctly before I updated the Spring Boot and Spring Cloud versions.

Comment: could you rename it back to data.sql and position it in src/main/resources and try again and if it does not work could you report also the startup exception?

Comment: `import.sql` is handled by Hibernate, not Spring Boot. Can you share the sample app you have somewhere so that we can run that ourselves?

Comment: Added the Sample Source Code Link. Actually, I updated my SQL file from ```data``` to ```import``` just to check multiple cases, as with SQL file name as an import in case3 at least I was able to start the Application.
I want to keep the SQL file name as data.sql only,  but then Case 4 needs to be checked, why it is failing.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.5.0 tries to run data.sql before applying the database schema. I had to revert to 2.4.6 where it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add this to the app config:

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

Since Spring Boot 2.5.0, the data.sql is executed before the schema initialization by default.

See also:

[Spring Boot Data JPA with H2 and data.sql - Table not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67744719/spring-boot-data-jpa-with-h2-and-data-sql-table-not-found/67744741#67744741)

Comment: Awesome @Dan.
The comment which you have added in the question for moving down to version ```2.4.6``` and the answer here for adding this property along with version ```2.5.0```, both solutions are working fine for me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Just to grab more details from Spring, I searched this property in spring documentation and found the details, so just sharing the link here [howto data-initialization using-basic-sql-scripts](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

What I found myself using Spring boot 2.5.0 is that you cannot add newline after table name.
With Spring Boot 2.5.0, import script should be named `import.sql`

So, this throws exception

```
INSERT into
 TRANSACTIONS (id, account_id, amount, currency, type) VALUES (5, 2, -10.00, 'GBP', 'MONEY_TRANSFER')
```

while this doesn't

````
INSERT into TRANSACTIONS (id, account_id, amount, currency, type) VALUES (5, 2, -10.00, 'GBP', 'MONEY_TRANSFER')```
````