# Spring Boot Data JPA with H2 and data.sql - Table not Found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a `Spring Boot` **2.5.0** project. I'm using `Spring Data JPA` with the `H2` *in-memory* database. I want to populate data on startup with a `data.sql` file but I'm getting a table not found exception. If I remove the `data.sql` file, I can see that a table for my entity does get created automatically. But if I include the `data.sql` file, I get the error saying the table doesn't exist. Maybe it is an error with my sql syntax of I have misconfigured the `H2` database?

*applicaltion.yml*

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: sa
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

debug: true
```

*data.sql*

```
INSERT INTO BUSINESS_SUMMARY VALUES (1, "ALM470", "B48", 3);
```

*BusinessSummary.java entity*

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
@Entity
public class BusinessSummary {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String businessId;
    private String businessDomainId;
    private Integer cityCode;
}
```

*BusinessSummaryRepository.java*

```
@Repository
public interface BusinessSummaryRepository extends JpaRepository<BusinessSummary, Long> {
}
```

*Exception:*

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "BUSINESS_SUMMARY" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO BUSINESS_SUMMARY VALUES(1, "ALM470", "B48", 3) [42102-200]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using **hibernate** as a JPA implementation, the best way I think is by using the file **import.sql** instead of data.sql for Database Initialization.

for more information on database initialization see the official Spring Boot documentation [Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization)

Answer (score 64):

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

> By default, `data.sql` scripts are now run before `Hibernate` is
> initialized. This aligns the behavior of basic script-based
> initialization with that of `Flyway` and `Liquibase`.

> If you want to use
> `data.sql` to populate a schema created by `Hibernate`, set
> **spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true**. While mixing
> database initialization technologies is not recommended, this will
> also allow you to use a `schema.sql` script to build upon a
> `Hibernate`-created schema before it’s populated via `data.sql`.

you'll have to convert `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization` to yml.

Comment: Good grief. I literally spent 2 solid weeks on this. I finally gave up in disgust and starting writing @BeforeEach code blocks on all unit tests to populate the H2 database with data because loading data.sql always resulted in 'TABLE <> NOT FOUND' errors. Hours and hours of frustration. This was the ticket:
 
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true 

Thank you so much!

Comment: this is very important to know , was stuck for days

Comment: Was scratching my head after bumping my spring boot version

Comment: This works perfectly fine. 
What also worked for me was to rename data.sql to import.sql (no idea why even without adding spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization)

Comment: By default, data.sql and schema.sql both run before **Hibernate**.  say, if you have a sequence start with 1000 in schema.sql, which is different from  your default sequence start in entity class,  without putting "spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization" in application.yml, sequence start with 1000 will be used.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to defer-datasource-initialization: true, you may also need

```
spring:
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true    
spring.sql.init.mode = always
```

if still doesn`t work try renaming the file from data.sql to import.sql